# Some questions about Qing Liu's proof of Valuative Criterion of Properness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm studying algebraic geometry by following Mumford's Red Book, but recently I found Qing Liu's book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves", which seems to be more careful and detailed in its proofs $-$ what I prefer, because I'm novice in this subject.

However, in Theorem 3.25 of Liu's book (pg 107) $-$ whose immediate corollary corresponds to Proposition 3 of Section 7 in Chapter 2 of Mumford's book $-$ I am just as stuck as when I was following Mumford's book.

The theorem is the following: (Theorem 3.25) Let $X$ be a proper scheme over a valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_K$, and let $K=\text{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_K)$. Then the canonical map $X(\mathcal{O}_K)\rightarrow X_K(K)$ is bijective.

This is the proof:[image]

Essentially I have "two" questions.

The first question: How this proof works? Although I feel bad for asking for a walkthrough to this proof, I can't "connect" its many statements in an one whole argument, at least no with the amount of knowledge I've got so far. In some sense, this question is the same as [Proof of $X(\mathcal{O}_K)\simeq X_K(K)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268665/proof-of-x-mathcalo-k-simeq-x-kk) , but without any "ok" on the part of surjectivity.

The second question: if one supposes $X$ to be affine, then this theorem can be proved by using some analogous result in commutative algebra in the context of tensor products?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for intuition, or literally a walkthrough of the technical portions of the proof? Also, if $X$ is also affine (over some affine scheme), then it's necessarily affine itself, and a finite extension of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Do you see then why this is clear?

Comment: Intuition would be also welcome, since it usually helps to build up formal proofs, but my problems reside in the technical portions. About the clarity of the affine case, I'm sorry but it is not quite clear to me.

Comment: Ok, so for injectivity, do you not understand the proof of Prop 3.11. I assume this says that if $W\to Z$ is an $S$-morphism, $W$ is reduced, and $Z$ is separated over $S$, the any open dense immersion $U\to W$ is an epimorphism. So, if two morphisms agree on $U$ they must be equal. This applies perfectly well with $W=S=\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ and $Z=X$. This gives injectivity. The proof of this comes from the fact that there is a scheme of agreement for any two morphisms $W\to Z$ which, since $Z/S$ is separated, is closed.

Comment: But, by assumption, this agreement scheme contains $U$, which is dense, and so $W$ must be all of $X$, as a topological space. But, since the only closed subscheme of a reduced scheme $X$, whose underlying topological space is $X$ itself, must be $X$, it follows that the two morphisms agree. Is this the type of thing you're after?

Comment: It is exactly this kind of walkthrough I am looking for... Although the injectivity part was already okay before, now it is cristal clear, thank you! Is the surjectivity part that I can't understand.

Comment: Which part of surjectivity are you having difficulty with?

Comment: In almost every step. For example: why can we assume that $x$ (as defined in the proof) belongs to $X$? Also, why is $Z$ proper over $\mathcal{O}_K$? The problem goes on yet in the next steps... My first contact with schemes was about three weeks ago, so I am not quite familiar with the behavior of them.